# Add additional value to array built from variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("select GROUP_CONCAT( cohort_id SEPARATOR ',') as cohort_id from ( select distinct cohort_id from table_cohorts) as m"); 
$stmt2->execute(); 
$row2 = $stmt2->fetch();
$cohorts_allowed = explode(",",$row2["cohort_id"]);
$value = array ('amount', $cohorts_allowed );
```

`$cohorts_allowed` gives me something like "database_percent, national_percent". It is generated from all the possible `cohort_id`s in my database.

What I need to do is get all of these and add in the additional value 'amount' (which is not in my database) into the array.

How can I do this. You can see I tried to do this on the last line of my code above, but obviously that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cohorts_allowed = explode(",",$row2["cohort_id"]);
$cohorts_allowed['amount'] = 'amount' ;
```

or

```
$cohorts_allowed = explode(",",$row2["cohort_id"]);
$cohorts_allowed[] = 'amount' ;
```

How this works:

```
<pre>
<?php

$row2["cohort_id"] = "database_percent, national_percent";
$cohorts_allowed = explode(",",$row2["cohort_id"]);

print_r($cohorts_allowed);

/* output
Array
(
    [0] => database_percent
    [1] =>  national_percent

)
* The last index is 1
*/

$cohorts_allowed[] = 'amount' ;

print_r($cohorts_allowed);

/* output
Array
(
    [0] => database_percent
    [1] =>  national_percent
    [2] => amount
)
* The last index is 2 (after 1) and have the value amount.
* 
*/

?>
</pre>
```

You can read in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @jonmrich I edit with a example, don't forget check the answer as correct ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight.